# Python telebot. Взятия сообщений пользователя

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

Здраствуйте. Начал писать своего бота для Телеграма и столкнулся с проблемой. Какой метод позволяет ожидать от пользователя сообщений, а потом брать текст с них чтобы потом можно было выполнять какие-то действия над ним?
Например:

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "a=")
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "b=")
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, a+b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации по [pyTelegram](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI)  это указано. Для отслеживания сообщений есть handler, например такой

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['randnumber'])
```

отслеживает команду /randnumber и дальше выполняет прописанную под этим handler-ом функцию. Функция задается таким образом:

```
def func_name(message)
```

где **func_name** - имя функции, а **message** - собственно, само сообщение с командой (ну или не с командой, зависит от того, какой handler у вас прописан). Само сообщение приходит вроде как в JSON формате. Собственно текст из сообщения вытаскивается так:

```
quant = message.text
```

Вообще, из сообщения можно вытащить много чего, для простоты можно просто прописать в начале функции

```
print(message)
```

и потом смотреть, что вам оттуда надо.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что так берем только сообщения с командой? А как взять сообщения, которые идут после команды? Т.е. написал команду, ввел значения, получил результат.

Comment: Посмотрите вот этот [пример](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py), по-моему, ваш случай